# Display Y-Values on Y-Axis without rounding

Tags: c#, charts

How to remove rounding axis OY in Chart ?

I pass a value in the format 1,3546 and the graph shows 1,35.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a given `Axis` you can set the `LabelStyle.Format`.

For example you can use this :

```
  chart1.ChartAreas["area1"].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "000.000\\%";
```

or this:

```
  chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "###,##0.00000";
```

**Note:** This formats the `Label` of the Axis **Grid**, hence what you perceive as *rounding*. In fact it is the value for the `GridLines` **not** the Values of the `DataPoints`!

To display the Y-Values of the `DataPoints` you have three options I know of and I'll show you each:

1. You can display them inside the graph with each point
2. You can display them as tooltips when the mouse is over a point
3. or you can display them in  `CustomLabels` along the Y-Axis, which may  be what you want. Please note that this will only be a useful option if

- There is a very limited number of data points
- Those points are spread out reasonably far apart

If one or both conditions are not met, the `CustomLabels`  will overlap.

Setting `CustomLabels` is somewhat tricky. Here is a piece of code that sets one per each data point. As noted you may need to insert checks to prevent the overlapping..

```
// propare a few short names
ChartArea CA = chart1.ChartAreas[0];
Series S1 = chart1.Series[0];

// this would be option one:
S1.IsValueShownAsLabel = true;

// we clear any previous CustomLabels
CA.AxisY.CustomLabels.Clear();
// we create a version of our points collection which sorted  by Y-Values:
List<DataPoint> ptS = S1.Points.OrderBy(x => x.YValues[0]).ToList();

// now, for option three we add the custom labels:
for (int p = 0; p < ptS.Count; p++)
{
    CustomLabel L = new CustomLabel(ptS[p].YValues[0] - 0.5, 
                                    ptS[p].YValues[0] + 0.5,  
                                    ptS[p].YValues[0].ToString("##0.0000"), 
                                    0, LabelMarkStyle.None);
    CA.AxisY.CustomLabels.Add(L);

    // this is option two: tooltips for each point
    ptS[p].ToolTip = ptS[p].YValues[0].ToString("##0.0000");
}
```

The first two parameters of a `CustomLabel` are about the Y-position or actually the Y-Value range they are supposed to label. Next the value, formatted to show the decimal digits you wanted. Finally first row of labels and no tickmarks.

Here is a screenshot that shows all three options at work:

[image: CustomLabels]

Comment: now I pass a value in the format 1,3546 and the graph shows 1,3500

Comment: That's right, the labels are for the grid lines, not the data points. See my updated answer to learn how to display those..!

Comment: If you find the answer helpful please consider ['accepting'](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it by clicking on the checkmark on its top left below the votes, which apears when you move the mouse there..